# Can't search contacts

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

So I have made a list of static contacts, and I have tried to add a search bar, however I can't search the contacts using the search bar. When I click on search bar it will open but then close. The keyboard pops up for a moment but then will close. The idea was to make the search predictive, so when a name is typed in, it will list the closed based on the names in the database. Any ideas?

```
class ContactsPage extends StatefulWidget {
  Widget appBarTitle = new Text("Contacts");
  Icon actionIcon = new Icon(Icons.search);
```

Comment: Can you give the sample `kContacts` value to run it our local?

Answer (score 1):

I have updated the code with **predictive search** and removed the unused codes.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Contact {
  final String fullName;

  const Contact({this.fullName});
}

void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: ContactsPage(),
    ));

class ContactsPage extends StatefulWidget {
  Widget appBarTitle = new Text("Contacts");
  Icon actionIcon = new Icon(Icons.search);
  final List<Contact> contacts = [
    Contact(
      fullName: 'Ganesh',
    ),
    Contact(
      fullName: 'Dinesh',
    ),
    Contact(
      fullName: 'Somesh',
    ),
    Contact(
      fullName: 'Ramesh',
    )
  ];

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return new _ContactPage(contacts);
  }
}

class _ContactPage extends State<ContactsPage> {
  List<Contact> filteredContacts;

  _ContactPage(this.filteredContacts);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      home: new Scaffold(
          appBar: new AppBar(
            title: widget.appBarTitle,
            actions: <Widget>[
              new IconButton(
                icon: widget.actionIcon,
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    if (widget.actionIcon.icon == Icons.search) {
                      widget.actionIcon = new Icon(Icons.close);
                      widget.appBarTitle = new TextField(
                        style: new TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ),
                        decoration: new InputDecoration(
                            prefixIcon:
                                new Icon(Icons.search, color: Colors.white),
                            hintText: "Search...",
                            hintStyle: new TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
                        onChanged: (value) {
                          filterContacts(value);
                        },
                      );
                    } else {
                      widget.actionIcon =
                          new Icon(Icons.search); //reset to initial state
                      widget.appBarTitle = new Text("Contacts");
                      filteredContacts = widget.contacts;
                    }
                  });
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
          body: new ContactList(filteredContacts)),
      // replace the body with your contacts list view
    );
  }

  void filterContacts(String value) {
    var temp = widget.contacts.where((contact) {
      return contact.fullName.contains(value);
    }).toList();
    setState(() {
      filteredContacts = temp;
    });
  }
}

class ContactList extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<Contact> _contacts;

  ContactList(this._contacts);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return new _ContactListItem(this._contacts[index]);
        },
        itemCount: this._contacts.length,
        padding: new EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0));
  }
}

class _ContactListItem extends ListTile {
  _ContactListItem(Contact contact)
      : super(
            title: new Text(contact.fullName),
            leading: new CircleAvatar(child: new Text(contact.fullName[0])));
}
```

Refer the screen shots:
[image]

Comment: @Dinesh_Balasubramanianit doesn't allow me to search contacts when clicking in the search bar. No keyboard shows up.

Comment: The above code works for me. Did you make any change

Comment: @ Dinesh_Balasubramanian Still does the same thing, I will test on different phone. You wouldn't be able to look at my other flutter questions?

Comment: Are you testing in simulator?

Comment: No, running of device. Emulator isn't supported on my laptop

Comment: can you try in another phone and let me know. and also i answered your question

Comment: Thanks, for some reason it doesn't run correctly on my phone.