# Flutter - Implementing a listView search feature

Tags: ios, listview, dart, flutter, uisearchbar

I've been trying to implement a search bar into my app for bringing selected `listView` items to the top of a list. The list contains quite a few items, around approximately 1700 so the addition of a search bar is essential. I'd like the listView search box to appear from a `search` icon on the right hand side of the top `appBar`. Below is a picture of the current view for reference.

When you click the search `iconButton` a search field should replace the title in the `appBar`. It's going to be evident to the user that this is for the crypto `listView` as I'll add a hint in the search view identifying this.

[image: current crypto app view]

I'm not including all my code as this would be cumbersome for a stack question, but below is my `home_page.dart` file, where as the rest of my classes for the bottom crypto `listView` can be found at [this GitHub repo](https://github.com/iampawan/CryptoApp).

This is what my 'home_page.dart` looks like;

```
import 'package:cryptick/cryptoData/crypto_data.dart';
import 'package:cryptick/cryptoData/trending_data.dart';
import 'package:cryptick/modules/crypto_presenter.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/gestures.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'background.dart';

//FOLLOWING DART CODE COPYRIGHT OF 2017 - 2018 SQUARED SOFTWARE LONDON

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => new _HomePageState();
}

class ServerStatusScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        iconTheme: new IconThemeData(color: Colors.white),
        centerTitle: true,
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
        title: new Text(
          'API Server Status',
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          style: new TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white, fontSize: 27.5, fontFamily: 'Kanit'),
        ),
      ),
      body: new Center(
        child: new Column(
          children: [
            new Divider(color: Colors.white),
            new Text(
              'News Feed: ',
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              style: new TextStyle(
                color: Colors.black,
                fontSize: 27.5,
                fontFamily: 'Kanit',
              ),
            ),
            new Divider(),
            new Text(
              'Crypto Feed: ',
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              style: new TextStyle(
                color: Colors.black,
                fontSize: 27.5,
                fontFamily: 'Kanit',
              ),
            ),
            new Divider(),
            new Wrap(
              alignment: WrapAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                new Chip(
                  backgroundColor: Colors.black,
                  label: new Text(
                    '© 2017-2018 Squared Software',
                    style: new TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 15.0,
                      fontFamily: 'Poppins',
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MoreInfoScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final ThemeData themeData = Theme.of(context);
    final TextStyle aboutTextStyle = themeData.textTheme.body2;
    final TextStyle linkStyle =
        themeData.textTheme.body2.copyWith(color: themeData.accentColor);
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        iconTheme: new IconThemeData(color: Colors.white),
        centerTitle: true,
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
        title: new Text(
          'More Info',
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          style: new TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white, fontSize: 27.5, fontFamily: 'Kanit'),
        ),
      ),
      body: new Center(
        child: new Column(
          children: [
            new Divider(color: Colors.white),
            new ListTile(
                title: new Text('Squared Software',
                    style: new TextStyle(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                      fontFamily: 'Poppins',
                    )
                  ),
                leading: new CircleAvatar(
                    radius: 30.0,
                    backgroundImage: new AssetImage(
                        'images/sqinterlock.png'
                        )
                      )
                    ),
            new Divider(),
            new Text('Where do we get our information?',
                style: new TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.black,
                  fontFamily: 'Poppins',
                  fontSize: 16.5,
                )
              ),
            new Divider(color: Colors.white),
            new Text(
              "News Feed: bit.ly/2MFpzHX",
              style: new TextStyle(
                fontFamily: 'Poppins',
                fontSize: 16.5,
              ),
            ),
            new Divider(color: Colors.white),
            new Text(
              "Crypto Feed: bit.ly/2iIdJht",
              style: new TextStyle(
                fontFamily: 'Poppins',
                fontSize: 16.5,
              ),
            ),
            new Divider(color: Colors.white),
            new Wrap(
              alignment: WrapAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                new Chip(
                  backgroundColor: Colors.black,
                  label: new Text(
                    '© 2017-2018 Squared Software',
                    style: new TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 15.0,
                      fontFamily: 'Poppins',
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> implements CryptoListViewContract {
  CryptoListPresenter _presenter;
  List<Crypto> _currencies;
  bool _isLoading;
  final List<MaterialColor> _colors = [Colors.blue, Colors.indigo, Colors.red];

  _HomePageState() {
    _presenter = new CryptoListPresenter(this);
  }

  @override
  void onLoadTrendingComplete(Trending trending) {
    // TODO:
    articlesMap = trending.articles;

    for (Map articleMap in articlesMap) {
      articles.add(Articles.fromMap(articleMap));
    }

    if (mounted) setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  void onLoadTrendingError() {
    // TODO:
  }

  List articlesMap = [];
  List<Articles> articles = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _isLoading = true;
    _presenter.loadCurrencies();
    _presenter.loadTrending();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
          title: new Text(
            "Cryp - Tick Exchange",
            style: new TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white,
              fontFamily: 'Poppins',
              fontSize: 22.5,
            ),
          ),
          iconTheme: new IconThemeData(color: Colors.white),
          backgroundColor: const Color(0xFF273A48),
          elevation: 0.0,
          centerTitle: true,
        ),
        drawer: new Drawer(
          child: new ListView(padding: EdgeInsets.zero, children: <Widget>[
            new DrawerHeader(
              child: new CircleAvatar(
                child: new Image.asset('images/ctavatar.png'),
              ),
              decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.black,
              ),
            ),
            new MaterialButton(
                child: new Text(
                  'Server Status',
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 27.5, fontFamily: 'Kanit'),
                ),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) => ServerStatusScreen()),
                  );
                }),
            new Divider(),
            new MaterialButton(
                child: new Text(
                  'More Info',
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 27.5, fontFamily: 'Kanit'),
                ),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MoreInfoScreen()),
                  );
                }),
            new Divider(),
            new Wrap(
              alignment: WrapAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                new Chip(
                  backgroundColor: Colors.black,
                  label: new Text(
                    'v0.0.1',
                    style: new TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 15.0,
                      fontFamily: 'Poppins',
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ]),
        ),
        body: _isLoading
            ? new Center(child: new CupertinoActivityIndicator(radius: 15.0))
            : _allWidget());
  }


  Widget _allWidget() {
    final _width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    final _height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
//CRYPTO FEED CRYPTO FEED CRYPTO FEED CRYPTO FEED CRYPTO FEED CRYPTO FEED CRYPTO FEED CRYPTO FEED CRYPTO FEED CRYPTO FEED CRYPTO FEED CRYPTO FEED CRYPTO FEED CRYPTO FEED
    final headerList = new ListView.builder(
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        EdgeInsets padding = index == 0
            ? const EdgeInsets.only(
                left: 20.0, right: 10.0, top: 4.0, bottom: 30.0)
            : const EdgeInsets.only(
                left: 10.0, right: 10.0, top: 4.0, bottom: 30.0);
        return new Padding(
          padding: padding,
          child: new InkWell(
            onTap: () {
              print('@url');
            },
            child: new Container(
              decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                color: const Color(0xFF273A48),
                boxShadow: [
                  new BoxShadow(
                    color: Colors.black.withAlpha(70),
                    offset: const Offset(3.0, 10.0),
                      blurRadius: 15.0)
                ],
                image: new DecorationImage(
                  image: new NetworkImage(articles[index].urlToImage),
                  fit: BoxFit.fitHeight,
                ),
              ),
              height: 200.0,
              width: 275.0,
              child: new Stack(
                children: <Widget>[
                  new Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                    child: new Container(
                      padding: new EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0),
                        decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                          color: const Color(0xFF273A48),
                          borderRadius: new BorderRadius.only(
                              bottomLeft: new Radius.circular(10.0),
                              bottomRight: new Radius.circular(10.0)),
                        ),
                        height: 50.0,
                        child: new Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            new Expanded(child: new Text(
                              articles[index].title,
                              overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                              maxLines: 2,
                              style: new TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.white,
                                fontFamily: 'Poppins',
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      )
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      itemCount: articles.length,
    );

    final body = new Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      body: new Container(
        child: new Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            new Padding(
              padding: new EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0),
              child: new Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                  new Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                    child: new Padding(
                        padding: new EdgeInsets.only(
                          left: 10.0,
                        ),
                        child: new Text(
                          "Trending News",
                          style: new TextStyle(
                            letterSpacing: 0.8,
                            fontFamily: 'Kanit',
                            fontSize: 17.5,
                            color: Colors.white,
                          ),
                        )),
                  ),
                  new Container(
                      height: 300.0, width: _width, child: headerList),
                  new Expanded(child: ListView.builder(
                      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    final int i = index;
                    final Crypto currency = _currencies[i];
                    final MaterialColor color = _colors[i % _colors.length];
                    return new ListTile(
                      title: new Column(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          new Row(
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                            children: <Widget>[
                              new Container(
                                height: 72.0,
                                width: 72.0,
                                decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    boxShadow: [
                                      new BoxShadow(
                                          color: Colors.black.withAlpha(80),
                                          offset: const Offset(2.0, 2.0),
                                          blurRadius: 15.0)
                                    ],
                                    borderRadius: new BorderRadius.all(
                                        new Radius.circular(35.0)),
                                    image: new DecorationImage(
                                      image: new ExactAssetImage(
                                        "cryptoiconsBlack/" +
                                            currency.symbol.toLowerCase() +
                                            "@2x.png",
                                      ),
                                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                    )),
                              ),
                              new SizedBox(
                                width: 8.0,
                              ),
                              new Expanded(
                                  child: new Column(
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  new Text(
                                    currency.name,
                                    style: new TextStyle(
                                        fontSize: 15.0,
                                        fontFamily: 'Poppins',
                                        color: Colors.black87,
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                  ),
                                  _getSubtitleText(currency.price_usd,
                                      currency.percent_change_1h),
                                ],
                              )),
                            ],
                          ),
                          new Divider(),
                        ],
                      ),
                    );
                  }))
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );

    return new Container(
      decoration: new BoxDecoration(
        color: const Color(0xFF273A48),
      ),
      child: new Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          new CustomPaint(
            size: new Size(_width, _height),
            painter: new Background(),
          ),
          body,
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

// CRYPTO FEED CRYPTO FEED CRYPTO FEED CRYPTO FEED CRYPTO FEED CRYPTO FEED CRYPTO FEED CRYPTO FEED CRYPTO FEED CRYPTO FEED CRYPTO FEED CRYPTO FEED CRYPTO FEED CRYPTO FEED

  Widget _getSubtitleText(String priceUSD, String percentageChange) {
    TextSpan priceTextWidget = new TextSpan(
        text: "\$$priceUSD\n",
        style: new TextStyle(
          color: Colors.black,
          fontSize: 14.0,
        ));
    String percentageChangeText = "1 hour: $percentageChange%";
    TextSpan percentageChangeTextWidget;

    if (double.parse(percentageChange) > 0) {
      percentageChangeTextWidget = new TextSpan(
          text: percentageChangeText,
          style: new TextStyle(
            color: Colors.green,
            fontFamily: 'PoppinsMediumItalic',
          ));
    } else {
      percentageChangeTextWidget = new TextSpan(
          text: percentageChangeText,
          style: new TextStyle(
            color: Colors.red,
            fontFamily: 'PoppinsMediumItalic',
          ));
    }

    return new RichText(
        text: new TextSpan(
            children: [priceTextWidget, percentageChangeTextWidget]));
  }

  //Works with cryptoListViewContract implimentation in _MyHomePageState
  @override
  void onLoadCryptoComplete(List<Crypto> items) {
    // TODO: implement onLoadCryptoComplete

    setState(() {
      _currencies = items;
      _isLoading = false;
    });
  }

  @override
  void onLoadCryptoError() {
    // TODO: implement onLoadCryptoError
  }
}
```

Thanks for the help, Jake

Comment: Have you consider [AppBar.actions](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/AppBar/actions.html)? If so, what is the desired affect? That is, do you want a have a dialog pop up to search? Would be cool to have an TextField instead of an Icon and you just expand that our while hiding the other parts of the AppBar.

Comment: Yeah I'll edit the question after this to reflect this comment but is there anyway when you click the search `iconButton` a search field could replace the title in the `appBar`?. It's going to be evident to the user that this is for the crypto `listView` as I'll add a hint in the search view identifying this. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are probably many ways to implement this based on the resulting experience you want. A simple solution is to **create `activeSearch` state that toggles a 'search app bar' and a 'normal app bar'**

Here's the normal app bar:

```
return AppBar(
  title: Text("My App"),
  actions: <Widget>[
    IconButton(
      icon: Icon(Icons.search),
      onPressed: () => setState(() => activeSearch = true),
    ),
  ],
);
```

And here's the search app bar:

```
return AppBar(
  leading: Icon(Icons.search),
  title: TextField(
    decoration: InputDecoration(
      hintText: "here's a hint",
    ),
  ),
  actions: <Widget>[
    IconButton(
      icon: Icon(Icons.close),
      onPressed: () => setState(() => activeSearch = false),
    )
  ],
);
```

**Note: if you don't want to have a leading icon when search is active you may want to disable the default behavior for a `drawer` and `back button` icon with:**

> automaticallyImplyLeading: false

Full example:

```
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  bool activeSearch;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    activeSearch = false;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: _appBar(),
      drawer: _drawer(),
    );
  }

  PreferredSizeWidget _appBar() {
    if (activeSearch) {
      return AppBar(
        leading: Icon(Icons.search),
        title: TextField(
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            hintText: "here's a hint",
          ),
        ),
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.close),
            onPressed: () => setState(() => activeSearch = false),
          )
        ],
      );
    } else {
      return AppBar(
        title: Text("My App"),
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.search),
            onPressed: () => setState(() => activeSearch = true),
          ),
        ],
      );
    }
  }

  Widget _drawer() {
    return Container();
  }
}
```

[image]

[image]

UPDATE: Here's a hint at handling results

```
return AppBar(
  ...
  title: TextField(
    onChanged: _search,
  ),
);
```

And what _search *could* look like:

```
  List<MyResultObject> _results;

  void _search(String queryString) {
    // do some searching and sorting
    // then call setState() with the results
    // and then in your ListView you can read from results
    // (handle empty, default case as well in view)
    setState(() {
      _results = ...
    });
  }

  List<Widget> _resultWidgets() {
    if (_results.isEmpty) return _defaultWidgets();
    _results.map((r) => _buildRowWidget(s)).toList();
  }
```

Comment: This looks great, just implementing it now

Comment: Is there anyway you could provide or hint at the code I would need to actually sort the items? The search bar is really good thanks for what you've done so far.

Comment: @Jake, I added quick update at the end that may help

Comment: Brilliant, thanks for the help. I'll take a look at the question @Dinesh Balasubramanian provided and reference it soon.

Comment: Hey @Ashton, just noticed that when the on screen iOS keyboard pops up when I type a value to the search field, I get a severe pixel overflow. Anything I could do about this? Thanks

Comment: You need to wrap the body of your scaffold in a listview to creat a scrollable area

Answer (score 1):

Can u refer a simple search view in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51973379/5305962) answer. In that example, as the user types, the list will get filtered.

Comment: I'll implement the question from Ashton first, then I'll add that after. Thanks for the additional info :)