# type 'Future<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Application>?'

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-dependencies

I am trying to create a search widget in flutter, for list I used the application list using device_apps (https://pub.dev/packages/device_apps). But Im getting an error "type 'Future' is not a subtype of type 'List?'" . To create the search widget I used help from [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59397792/flutter-implementing-a-search-feature-for-data-from-a-streambuilder-with-listvi).

Here is my code:

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:device_apps/device_apps.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


class SearchWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  SearchWidget({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          TextField(onChanged: _filter),
          StreamBuilder<List<Application>>(
            initialData: lelist(),
            stream: _stream,
            builder:
                    (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<Application>> snapshot) {
                  print(snapshot.data);
                  return ListView.builder(
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                      return Text(snapshot.data[index].appName);
                    },
                  );
                },
              )


        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

StreamController<List<Application>> _streamController = StreamController<List<Application>>();
Stream<List<Application>> get _stream => _streamController.stream;
_filter(String searchQuery) {
  List<Application> _filteredList = lelist()
      .where((Application app) => app.appName.toLowerCase().contains(searchQuery.toLowerCase()))
      .toList();
  _streamController.sink.add(_filteredList);
}

lelist() async {
  List<Application> _dataFromQuerySnapShot = await DeviceApps.getInstalledApplications(includeAppIcons: true);
  _dataFromQuerySnapShot.sort((a, b) {
    return a.appName.toString().toLowerCase().compareTo(b.appName.toString().toLowerCase());
  });
  return _dataFromQuerySnapShot;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there it is unnecessary to load and sort the installed apps on every keystroke and therefore put all of this logic into initState. This also makes your `_filter` function synchronous.

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:device_apps/device_apps.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SearchWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  SearchWidget({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _SearchWidgetState createState() => _SearchWidgetState();
}

class _SearchWidgetState extends State<SearchWidget> {
  final _streamController = StreamController<List<Application>>();
  List<Application> _dataFromQuerySnapShot;

  Stream<List<Application>> get _stream => _streamController.stream;

  @override
  void initState() {
    DeviceApps.getInstalledApplications(includeAppIcons: true)
        .then((List<Application> apps) {
      _dataFromQuerySnapShot = apps;
      _dataFromQuerySnapShot.sort((a, b) {
        return a.appName
            .toString()
            .toLowerCase()
            .compareTo(b.appName.toString().toLowerCase());
      });
      _streamController.sink.add(_dataFromQuerySnapShot);
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _streamController.close();
    super.dispose();
  }

  _filter(String searchQuery) {
    final filteredApplications = _dataFromQuerySnapShot
        .where((Application app) =>
            app.appName.toLowerCase().contains(searchQuery.toLowerCase()))
        .toList();
    _streamController.sink.add(filteredApplications);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          TextField(onChanged: _filter),
          StreamBuilder<List<Application>>(
            stream: _stream,
            builder: (BuildContext context,
                AsyncSnapshot<List<Application>> snapshot) {
              if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
              }
              return snapshot.data.isEmpty
                  ? Center(child: Text('Empty'))
                  : ListView.builder(
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                        return Text(snapshot.data[index].appName);
                      },
                    );
            },
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried that but got the error: "The argument type 'Future<List<Application>>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<Application>'"

Comment: You cannot use `lelist()` as a value for your initialData as it is returning a Future. Either provide a different value for initialData or remove it and instead use something like `if (!snapshot.hasData) { return CircularProgressIndicator() }` while waiting for the first value from your stream.

Comment: I removed the initialData and used CircularProgressIndicator()...but now in print(snapshot.data) im getting I/flutter (26265): null and the Circular Indicator is rotating without showing any list...... When I entered words in the TextField I got another error in the console : Unhandled Exception: type 'Future<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Application>'

Comment: I tried using initialData: lelist() as List<Application>, but it is showing the same error : 'Future<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Application>' in type cast

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add asList after calling your future.

```
lelist() async {
 List<Application> _dataFromQuerySnapShot = await 
   DeviceApps.getInstalledApplications(includeAppIcons: true);
    _dataFromQuerySnapShot.sort((a, b) {
    return 
    a.appName.toString().toLowerCase().compareTo(b.appName.toString().toLowerCase());
 }) as List;
 return _dataFromQuerySnapShot;
```

}

Comment: No, still got the same error even after using as List.